# Why do nested resource routes reset the namespace in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have a `Photo` model and a `Post` model, and I want both of those to have `Comment`'s. In Rails, my routes would look like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts, only: [ :show ] do
    resources :comments, only: [ :index ]
  end

  resources :photos, only: [ :show ] do
    resources :comments, only: [ :index ]
  end
end
```

This generates the following routes:

```
GET /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)
GET /posts/:id(.:format)
GET /photos/:photo_id/comments(.:format)
GET /photos/:id(.:format)
```

Okay, makes sense. If I want to get the path to the `Comment`'s for the `Photo` with an ID of `9`, I'd use `photo_comments(9)`.

If I wanted to create the same routes in Ember, I'd do:

```
App.Router.map () ->

  @resource 'posts', ->
    @resource 'post', { path: '/:post_id' }, ->
      @resource 'comments'

  @resource 'photos', ->
    @resource 'photo', { path: '/:photo_id' }, ->
      @resource 'comments'
```

In Ember, this generates the following URLs:

```
#/loading
#/posts/loading
#/posts/:post_id/loading
#/posts/:post_id
#/posts
#/photos/:photo_id/comments
#/photos/:photo_id/loading
#/photos/:photo_id
#/photos/loading
#/photos
#/
#/photos/:photo_id/loading
```

I still have `/posts/:posts_id/comments` and `/photos/:photo_id/comments`, which is what I wanted. However, because Ember resets the namespace, I no longer have `post_comments` and `photo_comments` helpers. I have a `comments` route, which routes to `/photos/:photo_id/comments`, but I don't have any way of routing to `/posts/:posts_id/comments`. I realize I could fix this by doing the following, but it seems redundant:

```
App.Router.map () ->

  @resource 'posts', ->
    @resource 'post', { path: '/:post_id' }, ->
      @resource 'posts.comments', { path: '/comments' }

  @resource 'photos', ->
    @resource 'photo', { path: '/:photo_id' }, ->
      @resource 'photos.comments', { path: '/comments' }
```

**TL/DR:**

I understand *that* Ember resets routes for nested resources, but I don't understand *why*. Could somebody explain it to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR Resources must be unique due to the transitioning paradigm, and really you're just over-writing the comments resource.

It's because when you transition to routes you don't explicitly call out an entire path.

```
this.transitionTo('photo', photo);

{{#link-to 'photo' photo}} My photo{{/link-to}}
```

Because of this resources must be unique.

If you were at the root of your app and wanted to jump 2 levels deep, to a photo you would just use `this.transitionTo('photo', photo)`, and would **NOT** use `this.transitionTo('photos.photo', photo)`

If you are transitioning to a resource that is multiple dynamic resources deep you just send in multiple models.  `this.transitionTo('foo', bar, baz)`.

As was implied, you could force people to state an entire path while doing transitionTo/link-to, but the authors decided to punish the smaller percent of people with duplicate resources vs punish everyone into defining the entire path while transitioning.

Additionally it's understood that `foo.bar` represents `resource.route` in Ember.  I wouldn't consider this an argument for why it was architected as it was, more of a statement about it.

```
@resource 'posts', ->
   @resource 'post', { path: '/:post_id' }
   @route 'foo'

this.transitionTo('posts.foo');
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for the prompt and detailed answer.

Comment: I've posted a [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23947532/creating-a-new-resource-in-ember). Would you mind taking a look at it?