# Creating a new resource in ember

Tags: ember.js, routes

I'm building an office reception app in Ember. When a person arrives at the office, they pop open the app and are taken through a three step wizard:

- Choose a reason for visiting
- Choose the person you've come to see
- Confirm

The app also allows an administrator to view all of the visits and to view an individual visit.

I have `Visit` and `Person` models I've hooked up to a server using Ember Data. Here's what my routes look like:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'visits', ->
    @resource 'visit', { path: '/:visit_id' }
    @resource 'new', ->
      @route 'welcome'
      @route 'directory'
      @route 'thanks'
```

This allows me to create a new `Visit` model in the `VisitsNewRoute` and use it in the `welcome`, `directory` and `thanks` views.

This works. However, it feels wrong to have a `new` resource, especially since it's conceivable I'll want at least one more `new` route in my application.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can change the `new` resource to `newVisit` like this:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'visits', ->
    @resource 'visit', { path: '/:visit_id' }
  @resource 'newVisit', ->
    @route 'welcome'
    @route 'directory'
    @route 'thanks'
```

Now you will have a `NewVisitRoute` where you can create a new `Visit` model to use in each of the child routes.

And you will be able to make a transition to this routes with the route names: `newVisit.welcome`, `newVisit.directory` and `newVisit.thanks`. You can use this route names in a `link-to` helper link this:

```
{{link-to "Welcome", "newVisit.welcome"}}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recommended practice is to use a `create`/`new` route under the resource type, so `new` under `visits`, then `transitionTo('visit.welcome', newRecord).  (I'm saying all of this with the assumption that welcome, directory, and thanks aren't part of the new record creation).

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'visits', ->
    @route 'new'
    @resource 'visit', { path: '/:visit_id' }
      @route 'welcome'
      @route 'directory'
      @route 'thanks'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The `welcome`, `directory` and `thanks` routes are the three steps for a user to create a `Visit`. The process is a little too complicated to put on one page. Also, the `directory` route will need to retrieve the list of people to display.

Answer (score 1):

Ember doesn't always name routes the way you want when dealing with routes nested more than one level.  I would name your 'new' route as follows:

```
@resource 'visits.new', path: 'new', ->
```

There are a number of approaches you can use to structuring your routes depending on how you assign model ids and whether or not you are using `localStorage` to preserve user edits until they are persisted to the server.

I have my route pattern as follows:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'visits', ->
    @route 'new'
    @route 'crud', path: ':visit_id'
```

My 'new' routes create a new resource in the routes `model` callback which in my models auto-generates a v4 UUID. The new route then performs a `transitionTo` the crud route in the `afterModel` callback.  In effect the 'visits.new' route acts as a trampoline and allows you to easily use `{{link-to 'visits.new'}}` from templates/menus etc.

The above approach allows you to to have a single crud route and crud controller that can handle all the show/create/update/delete actions for the model. The models `isNew` property can be used within your templates to handle any differences between create and update.

I also use `localStorage` so that newly created (but not yet persisted) models survive a browser refresh, the UUIDs really come in handy for both this and for persisting complex model graphs.

The above router pattern occurs quite a lot in my app so I have defined some base Route classes and a route class builder but the general pattern is as follows:

If using UUIDs:

```
App.VisitsNewRoute = Em.Route.extend
  model: (params, transition)->
    App.Visit.create(params)
  afterModel: (model,transition) ->
    @transitionTo 'visits.crud', model

App.VisitsCrudRoute = Em.Route.extend
   model: (params,transition) ->
    App.Visit.find(params['visit_id'])
```

If not using UUID's then the routes are different. I did something like this before I moved to UUIDs, it treats model id 'new' as a special case:

```
App.Router.map () ->
  @resource 'visits', ->
    @route 'crud', path: ':visit_id'

App.VisitsCrudRoute = App.Route.extend
   model: (params, transition) ->
     visit_id = params['visit_id']
     if visit_id == 'new' then App.Visit.create() else App.Visit.find(visit_id)
   serialize: (model, params) ->
     return if params.length < 1 or !model
     segment = {}
     segment[params[0]] = if model.isNew() then 'new' else model.get('id')
     segment
```

For your specific case of managing the wizard step state I would consider using Ember [Query Params](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/), which allow you specify the current step in a parameter at the controller level

Query params example:

```
App.VisitsCrudController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  queryParams: ['step'],
  step: 'welcome'
```

Link to next step in the view:

```
{{#link-to 'visits.crud' (query-params step="directory")}}Next{{/link-to}}
```

You may also want to define some computed properties for the next and previous steps, and some boolean properties such as `isWelcome`, `isDirectory` for your view logic.