# How do you navigate to a nested resource's route in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

Say I have this setup:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("people", {path: "people/:person_id"} function() {
    this.resource("male", {path: "male"}, function() {
      this.resource("clothingCollection", {collection/:collection_id}, function() {
        this.route("item", {path: "item/:item_id"});
      });
    });
    this.resource("female", {path: "female"}, function() {
      this.resource("clothingCollection", {collection/:collection_id}, function() {
        this.route("item", {path: "item/:item_id"});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

How do I navigate to people/female/x/clothingCollection/y/item/z?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you're at.  And resource names must be unique.

[Why do nested resource routes reset the namespace in Ember?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946960/why-do-nested-resource-routes-reset-the-namespace-in-ember)

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("people", {path: "people/:person_id"} function() {
    this.resource("male", {path: "male"}, function() {
      this.resource("maleClothingCollection", {collection/:collection_id}, function() {
        this.route("item", {path: "item/:item_id"});
      });
    });
    this.resource("female", {path: "female"}, function() {
      this.resource("femaleClothingCollection", {collection/:collection_id}, function() {
        this.route("item", {path: "item/:item_id"});
      });
    });
  });
});
```

I'd recommend changing it to something like this:

## Inside the people resource

#### From the template

```
{{#link-to 'clothingCollection.item' model}}Go there{{/link-to}}
```

#### From a route

```
this.transitionTo('clothingCollection.item', model);
```

#### From a controller

```
this.transitionToRoute('clothingCollection.item', model);
```

## Outside the people resource

#### From the template

```
{{#link-to 'clothingCollection.item' person item}}Go there{{/link-to}}
```

#### From a route

```
this.transitionTo('clothingCollection.item', person, item);
```

#### From a controller

```
this.transitionToRoute('clothingCollection.item', person, item);
```

Comment: How do you specify male or female?