# Ember resource reuse on router

Tags: ember.js

I would like to reuse a resource under multiple routes. Here is a simplified version of my router for example purposes:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("foo", function() {
    this.resource("comments", function() {
      this.route("show", {
        path: ":comment_id"
      });
    });
  });
  this.route("bar", function() {
    this.resource("comments", function() {
      this.route("show", {
        path: ":comment_id"
      });
    });
  });
});
```

As expected I can now access the following urls.

`/foo/comments/2`

`/bar/comments/2`

But when I want to use `transitionTo` in routes I only have access to `comments.show` or `foo.index`. There appears to be no way to specify which nesting to use (foo or bar) and it just defaults to the last one defined. I really need something like `foo.comments.show` but there is nothing available.

Should I be doing something differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Turns out resources need to unique. This is answered very well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23947152/3904603).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your comment resources to something unique and mapping the path to comments:

```
this.resource("commentsfoo", { path: '/comments'}, ...
...
this.resource("commentsbar", { path: '/comments'}, ...
```